# NSLog statements aren't working while unit tests are running

Tags: unit-testing, xcode, debugging

I am unit testing my app in xcode, but for some reason I can't see any printouts in the debugger console from the NSLog() statements in my implementation files.

Why would this be?  And how do I get my darned printouts??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11866977/580677) answer states that NSLog output is handled by the "test runner." It seems like all of standard error from the application under test is redirected. I could find no place in the xctest output (as visible in Xcode) that included NSLog messages, nor in any log file referred to by xctest. .

I found that replacing NSLog with printf lead to output visible in the console. .

Answer (score -2):

Barney,

Click on the error in your Build Results window (it will be the one with the red text), and you will see an icon to the right with three horizontal lines.

If you click on those three lines, then the results will show right underneath the error and it will give you all the information about the object/comparison/test case that failed.

Comment: This does not work for me.  The "three lines" button simply expands the "blah started/blah passed" messages that I already see in the console.