# Using NSLog in Unit Test, the output is too slow, only few times are fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, unit-testing, grand-central-dispatch

I'm facing a strange problem with using `NSLog` in iOS's unit test.

### The Code

Here is the test code I'm using in my unit test.

```c
- (void)testExample
{
  NSOperationQueue *newqueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
  NSURLRequest *request2 = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];

  dispatch_semaphore_t sema2 = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request2 queue:newqueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    //    NSLog(@"2: Data: %@", data);
    printf("2: Data: %s\n", [[data description] UTF8String]);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema2);
  }];

  //  sleep(2);
  dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema2, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  dispatch_release(sema2);

  NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
  NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

  dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"1: Data: %@", data);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
  }];

  //  sleep(2);

  dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  dispatch_release(sema);

  NSLog(@"Over");
}
```

#### To use the code

1. Create a simple iOS project with Unit Test.
2. Paste the code above to the xxxTest.m
3. Press ⌘ + u

### Patterns I tried

1. Change the order of 2 different urls, for example let `www.google.com` run at first or let `www.apple.com` run at first.
2. Change the use of `dispatch_semaphore_xxx` to `sleep()`.
3. Change `NSLog()` to `printf()`
4. Run this code as a Cocoa console app.
5. Remove the test of second URL request.

#### Results

1. Running time 0.4s ~ 30s
2. Running time 0.4s ~ 30s
3. Running time 0.4s ~ 30s
4. Running time ~0.4s
5. Running time ~0.4s

### Questions

1. What is happening when I try the first 3 patterns?
2. Do you have a similar problem with you?
3. Are there any solutions to these?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Don't have a search argument specified in the console window.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with SenTest and NSLog.  Basically, the logs are piped to the test runner, which sends the data back to the console window in XCode.

NSLog writes to stderr, so if you redirect that to a file, you can get your log data.

Unfortunately, it still takes a while to write it all back out, when everything is done.

If I need to log a bunch of data during a test, I'll redirect stderr to a file, then "tail -f" it while the test is running if I want to watch it scroll.  When it's over, I can then view the file in mvim or XCode.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried to redirect the NSLog to a file, but as you said, it still took a long time to output all the data. About using `tail -f`, I think that's a good idea.

Comment: I use dup2() to redirect stderr to a file, and the do NOT NSLog it back to the console, but open it as a normal file.  The problem is the way that it handles the logging, not buffered right, or something, but SenTest is certainly not setup to handle large NSLog contents.

Comment: Sounds like I need to fire a bug report to Apple.